# Partition stream data and obtain two different collections as a result

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of IDs `myIdList` and a map `myObjectMap` associating the ID with a corresponding object, `Map<String,Object>`.

I need to go through my list of IDs, and for each ID - if it's present in the map, add the object associated with it to a new list of objects, otherwise add the ID to a list of missing IDs.

I can easily do this using a simple for each loop:

```
List<String> myIdList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
Map<String,Object> myObjectMap = new HashMap<>();
        
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> missingObjIds = new ArrayList<>();

for(String id : myIdList) {
    Object obj = myObjectMap.get(id);
    if(obj == null) {
        missingObjIds.add(id);
    } else {
        objectList.add(obj);
    }
}
```

I would like to do this in a less verbose way using the Stream API, but I'm not sure how.

I've tried partitioning the stream, but that got me either a map with 2 lists of IDs (which would necessitate going through the list again to retrieve the mapped objects) or a list of objects with nulls for all the missing objects and no way to get the missing IDs.

I'm sure there has to be a way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt there's any clean way.

Comment: *I would like to do this in a less verbose way using the Stream API*.  Streams have a lot of overhead to do what they do.  And less verbose does not mean better or even more efficient.  Use a loop.

Comment: Does it have to be a Stream operation? You can do this as simple as `List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>(); List<String> missingObjIds = new ArrayList<>(myIdList); missingObjIds.removeIf(id -> myObjectMap.containsKey(id) && objectList.add(myObjectMap.get(id)));` You wouldn’t even need a new list for `missingObjIds` if the source `myIdList` supports removal and isn’t needed afterwards.

Comment: @Holger This way of using `removeIf()` is definitely interesting, and it's also performant and meets the requirement of conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very efficient, but you can do it.

```
List<String> myIdList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
Map<String,Object> myObjectMap = new HashMap<>();
myObjectMap.put("b", "B");

Map<Boolean, List<String>> partitioned = myIdList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(myObjectMap::containsKey));

List<Object> objectList = partitioned.get(true).stream()
    .map(myObjectMap::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> missingObjIds = partitioned.get(false);

System.out.println("objectList=" + objectList);
System.out.println("missingObjIds=" + missingObjIds);
```

output:

```
objectList=[B]
missingObjIds=[a, c]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is similar to what I attempted at first, but I want to try to avoid iterating through the list more than once.

Answer (score 0):

This logic can be implemented in a **single** stream-statement and without *side-effects* by using a custom `Collector`, which can be created using static factory method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)).

<sup>**Note:** I would not claim that this solution is less verbose than a `for`-loop. But it's definitely **performant** and **maintainable**, and the client code is **concise**.</sup>

For that, we would need to define a custom accumulation type, which should be represented by a *mutable object* capable of consuming stream elements and producing the final result.

Since we need to obtain two different lists, the result of the stream execution should the accumulation type itself exposing these two lists.

So, in a nut-shell, the *custom type*, let's call it `Partitioner`, which we would use to perform mutable reduction should wrap two list. It would be more versatile if we make it generic and add a `Function` and `Predicate`, which would be involved in partitioning the data to its properties.

And for convenience, we can implement [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html) interface.

That's how the stream-statement in the client code might look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> myIdList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    Map<String, Object> myObjectMap = Map.of("a", "Alice");

    Partitioner<String, Object> result = myIdList.stream()
        .collect(partition(myObjectMap::containsKey, myObjectMap::get));

    System.out.println(result.getItems());
    System.out.println(result.getKeys());
}
```

*Output:*

```
[Alice] // Values assated with the Keys that match the IDs from the list
[b, c]  // missing IDs
```

The factory method `partition()` producing an instance of `Collector()` might look like this:

```
public static <K, R> Collector<K, ?, Partitioner<K, R>> partition(Predicate<K> predicate,
                                                                  Function<K, R> mapper) {
    return Collector.of(
        () -> new Partitioner<>(predicate, mapper),
        Partitioner::accept,
        Partitioner::merge
    );
}
```

And that's how the *custom accumulation type* containing the actual logic might be implemented:

```
public static class Partitioner<K, R> implements Consumer<K> {
    
    private List<R> items = new ArrayList<>(); // objectList
    private List<K> keys = new ArrayList<>();  // missingObjIds
    private Predicate<K> shouldStoreItem;
    private Function<K, R> mapper;
    
    public Partitioner(Predicate<K> shouldStoreItem, Function<K, R> mapper) {
        this.shouldStoreItem = shouldStoreItem;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void accept(K k) {
        if (shouldStoreItem.test(k)) items.add(mapper.apply(k));
        else keys.add(k);
    }
    
    public Partitioner<K, R> merge(Partitioner<K, R> other) {
        items.addAll(other.items);
        keys.addAll(other.keys);
        return this;
    }
    
    // getters
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good example why the reactionary impulse to use streams everywhere is not always positive.

Comment: @erickson I would agree that bothering with implementing something like this for a single would be wasteful. But this Collector itself is generalized and reusable, the actual logic is entirely abstracted away from the client code. In case if you were implying that it's too complex, then I would doubt that the `for`-loop in the original code, which forces the reader of the code to move their eyes repeatedly up and down, is easier to digest than a class a containing a couple of straightforward two-line methods.

Comment: I wasn't implying excessive complexity. Yours is a solid solution for utilizing `Stream`. I was just noting that too many people ask how a stream *can* be used before questioning *whether* a stream should be used. Regarding the relative complexity, I have no doubt that your solution is more *complex* overall; that is, to provide your collector, you needed a thorough understanding of far more concepts. However, once completed, your work offers a simple usage pattern to others who might lack that understanding. I.e., that complexity is well-encapsulated, and that's good engineering.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a stream here is one way.

- this creates a an entry based on the presence of the id.
- it then groups those independent entries by the keys "Missing" and "Present"

The Data

```
 List<String> myIdList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
 Map<String, Object> myObjectMap = new HashMap<>();
 myObjectMap.put("c", "C");
```

The process

```
Map<String, List<Object>> map = myIdList.stream()
         .map(id-> {
             Entry<String, Object> entry;
             Object obj = myObjectMap.get(id);
             if (obj == null) {
                 entry = new SimpleEntry<>("Missing", id);
             } else {
                 entry = new SimpleEntry<>("Present", obj);
             }
             return entry;
         }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Collectors
                 .mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println(map.get("Present"));
System.out.println(map.get("Missing"));
```

prints

```
[C]
[a, b]
```

But I would you just stick with what you have.  It makes sense and works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a foreach circumstance.

```
myIdList.stream().forEach(i -> {
    boolean b = myObjectMap.get(i) == null ? missingObjIds.add(i) : objectList.add(myObjectMap.get(i));
});
```

Comment: Don't use `collection.stream().forEach()`. Just use `collection.forEach()`. But, updating a collection in (either) `forEach()` is an example of the [accumulator antipattern.](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-java-streams-2-brian-goetz/#mutable-reduction) Use a `Collector` or some suitable reduction instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement in a stream and with partitioning / helper class. However why make your loop complicated when 2 stream implementation is concise?

```
List<Object> objectList    = myIdList.stream()
      .map(myObjectMap::get).filter(Objects::nonNull).toList();
List<String> missingObjIds = myIdList.stream()
      .filter(Predicate.not(myObjectMap::containsKey)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

**BE SIMPLE!!!**

```java
List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
Map<String, Object> map = Map.of();

List<Object> objectList = ids.stream()
                             .filter(map::containsKey)
                             .map(map::get)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> missingIds = ids.stream()
                             .filter(id -> !map.containsKey(id))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```